# How can i change display none to block with button by JSS function?

Tags: javascript, css

I want make appear/disappear table in my page. I will click the button and it will show up and then i will click the same button again and it will disappear.

Js code:

```
function showtable1() {
var x = document.getElementById('table1');
if (x.style.display = 'none') {
  x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
 x.style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

css code:

```
#table1 {
    width: 64%;
    height: 80%;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -10%;
    transform: translate(0);
    display:none;
    background-color: rgba(247, 243, 243, 0.849);
}
```

Its appearing but when i trying to disappear its not working.

Comment: Hi. You’ve got a logic error in the `if` clause. Use `==` or `===` for comparison. If you use a single `=`. this value will be assigned to `x.style.display` and will always evaluate to true, immediately setting the value back to `block`.

Comment: toggle a css class, so much easier.

Comment: Ups, sorry i fix that. But this time i have different problem. I need to click two times to appear table. Is there any solution for this or its just me to have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing your if-statements wrong.

```
if (x.style.display = 'none')
```

With this line you are not checking if display is none, you are assigning it the value `none`
To compare values you have to use `==` or `===`
You can read here more about the difference between those two: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

But for your code it should look like that:

```
function showtable1() {
   var x = document.getElementById('table1');
   if (x.style.display === 'none') {
       x.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
       x.style.display === 'none';
   }
 }
```

Comment: thank your for your answer. But this time i have different problem. I need to click two times to appear table. Is there any solution for this or its just me to have this problem.